# Merging of csv breaks diacritical characters

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd, merge

I'm trying to merge some csv files. I do it on Windows with cmd, like `type *.csv >>` or with a batch file, containing

```
echo. > all.csv
for %%a in (*.csv) DO copy /b alle.csv+%%a all.csv
```

On one computer (win7x64) is merging no problem. But on another one (same win7x64) all diacritical characters (german: äüöß) are broken - instead of them there are only ´,,´.

The source files, which should be merged, have healthy diacritical characters - i open them with Notepad++ and Excel, as ANSI or Unicode - everything is OK.

How can i adjust the file merging to save diacritical signs?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment to @MCNDs answer the command `echo. > all.csv` will insert a space in front of all appended content, if the the csv files are in unicode format with BOMs the resulting files will be invalid as a BOM has only to be in the very first bytes

Comment: You mean `all.csv` instead of `alle.csv` in your code, right? Anyway, to create an empty file, use `> all.csv rem/` or `> all.csv break`; using `echo. > all.csv` writes a space followed by a line-break to the file...

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are several issues contributing to the unexpected results:

1. You try to create an empty file by `echo. > all.csv`, but this actually results in a file containing a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, followed by a line-break (<kbd>CR</kbd> + <kbd>LF</kbd>), ANSI-encoded. So you may have files that are differently encoded, which can cause troubles.

   To truly create an empty file, use `rem/ > all.csv`, `break > all.csv`, `type nul > all.csv` or `copy /Y nul all.csv`.
2. When combining files with `copy`, it can be problematic when the destination file is also one of the source files. When it is the first source file, the data of every other source files are appended; when it is not the first of the source files, an overwrite prompt may appear (unless you specify `/Y`) and data may be lost. Since you have given `*.csv` as the source file, we do actually not know which source file is enumerated first, so it could or may not be `all.csv`. So to avoid such trouble, you better delete the destination file before copying rather than create an empty file, like `del all.csv`.
3. Supposing you have Unicode files, they begin with a two-byte header `0xFF` + `0xFE`. When combining such files using `copy /B`, you have multiple of these headers within the file. To overcome this, do `copy /A` but within a Unicode `cmd` instance initiated by `cmd /U`:

   ```cmd
    cmd /U /C del all.csv ^& copy /A *.csv all.csv
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
copy /b *.csv all.txt & ren all.txt all.csv
```

or

```
2>nul del all.csv & copy /b *.csv all.csv
```

The `type` command can make some changes that could interfere in the process. Better use `copy /b` (with or without the `for`), but ensure the file being generated is not present or selected to avoid it being included as source in the process.

You should also ensure all your files have the same encoding. If some of them are Unicode/UTF-? with BOM and some not, depending of what the first file is selected, you could end with bad formated data.

Comment: Since he already uses `copy /b` and there are differences on the used computers I think the problem is somewhere else - even if I have no idea where.

Comment: @LotPings, not really sure (I will test later), but, Is it possible that the `echo. > all.csv` could interfere in the file `BOM`? and that leads to, what will happen if some files have BOM and some not? If it is not a NTFS partition (order know), is it relevant what the first selected file is? ...

Comment: the source files have all the same BOM setting - for sure, they are from the same source and created from the same process. These are AdWords Keyword Planners export files, delivered as csv. Notepad++ shows the encoding as `UCS-2 Little Endian`. Yes, all files are placed on NTFS - don't know however, on what they are created at Google.

Comment: @MCND Agreed, he better uses `type NUL >all.csv` to retain the file but reset to zero length without interfering with possible BOMs (byte order marks) from unicode files, which have to be the first  bytes in the file.